# Loading has_many options hash via a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I’ve got what’s becoming a complex model, and am trying to DRY it out. In the case of my has_many options, instead of having them repeat, I’d like to simply load them from a method on the class.

```
class ExampleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :related_things, get_association_hash(arg1)
  has_many :other_things, get_association_hash(arg2)

  def get_association_hash(arg)
    { :class_name => 'SomeClass', :conditions => ['table.column = ?', arg] }
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, this results in `undefined method ‘get_association_hash’ for #<Class:0x007f9ae9efe6c0>` when loading the class.

(As a sanity check, that method is fine if I just call it by itself, without including it in the has_many. Also, the actual class is considerably larger and so DRY is more helpful than in this small example.)

I do note that the error message mentions `Class`, and not my derived `ExampleClass`, so perhaps it has to do with how has_many is loaded, and where I define my method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_many` is just a class method so this:

```
has_many :related_things, get_association_hash(arg1)
```

is just a method call like any other and the receiver in that context is your `ExampleClass`. That means that `get_association_hash` needs to be a class method. You'll also have to define it *before* your `has_many` calls or you won't be able to call it where you want to:

```
class ExampleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.get_association_hash(arg)
    { :class_name => 'SomeClass', :conditions => ['table.column = ?', arg] }
  end
  has_many :related_things, get_association_hash(arg1)
  has_many :other_things, get_association_hash(arg2)
end
```

That might be a bit ugly and make a mess of the usual definition order. If that's the case, then you can push your `get_association_hash` method into a module and then include that module at the top of your class:

```
module Pancakes
  def self.included(base)
    # There are various different ways to do this, use whichever one you like best
    base.class_exec do
      def self.get_association_hash(arg)
        # ...
      end
    end
  end
end

class ExampleClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Pancakes
  has_many :related_things, get_association_hash(arg1)
  has_many :other_things, get_association_hash(arg2)
end
```

You'd probably call your module something more sensible than `Pancakes`, that's just my default name for things (because *foo* gets boring after awhile and I prefer [Fargo](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116282/) over tradition).